# Pointer to a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

How can I make a pointer to a member of a struct, thats an array of ints. This is how the struct looks like:

```
typedef struct {
    volatile int x[COORD_MAX];
    volatile int y[COORD_MAX];
    volatile int z[COORD_MAX];
    //... other variables
} coords;

coords abc;
```

`abc` is a global variable.
Now, I would like to get pointers to x,y and z arrays and save them to another array. Then acces them through passing a wanted index. Here is what I mean:

```
void test(int index1, int index2) 
{
    static volatile const int* coords_ptr[3] = {abc.x, abc.y, abc.z};
    coords_ptr[index1][index2] = 100;
}
```

So `index1` would select which type of coordinates to choose from (x,y,z). And `index2` would select which index of the coordinates to change.

Please note, that this is just a simplification of the code I am working on. But the principle is the same.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

I've written wrong code. Sorry for the confusion, this should be right now.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I mean in C.

Comment: In `test`, what `coords` object is the function operating on? `coords` is a type, not an object.

Comment: @nneonneo The compiler wasnt happy, because x,y and z are volatile so I needed to add it there to. Is it wrong?

Comment: ...are you still getting compiler errors? If so, you should post these errors.

Comment: Yes, but I was sure these errors pop up, because I completely failed with pointers. Will post.

Comment: `coords_ptr[index1][index2] = 100;` : `coords_ptr[index1][index2]` is `const` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one small mistake: you made the pointers point to `const volatile int`, which prevents you from writing to them.

Just write

```
static volatile int* coords_ptr[3] = {abc.x, abc.y, abc.z};
```

and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define COORD_MAX 3

typedef struct {
  volatile int x[COORD_MAX];
  volatile int y[COORD_MAX];
  volatile int z[COORD_MAX];
} coords;

coords abc;

void test(int index1, int index2)
{
  static volatile int* coords_ptr[3] = {abc.x, abc.y, abc.z};
  coords_ptr[index1][index2] = 100;
}

int main()
{
  test(0, 0);
  test(1, 1);
  printf("%i %i\n", abc.x[0], abc.y[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
100 100
```